# There's no point of My/Me staying here?

Tags: pronouns

> There's no point of ( ***me*** / ***my*** ) staying here anymore.

In grammar class, they taught me to use ***me*** for the Subject of the Gerund in a case like the one above, which ***me*** being the Object of the Preposition ***Of*** as well. However I saw lots of examples they use ***my*** in stead. Is it sort of ungrammatical-but-they-use-normally type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is still grammatically correct.

Staying can be used as a noun.

There is no point to my staying. = My staying has no point.

However, it sounds very old fashioned. Nobody uses staying as a noun.

Answer (score -1):

Traditionally, *-ing forms* can be either gerunds or participles.   Gerunds are substantive, doing the same kind of work that nouns typically do.   Participles are attributive, doing the same kind of work that adjectives typically do.

In your example, the entire phrase "[me/my] staying here" is the complete object of the preposition "of".   The simple object, the keyword that forms the phrase, must be some kind of noun-like thing.

When the phrase is "me staying here", that noun-like thing is the objective singular first-person pronoun "me".   The phrase "staying here" is a participial modifier of the pronoun.   When the phrase is "my staying here", that noun-like thing is the gerund.   The genitive singular first-person pronoun modifies the gerund phrase "staying here".

> There's no point of me anymore. 
>   There's no point of staying anymore.

This is less a question of which is grammatically right and more a question of which simple object is more sensible.   Both possibilities are available, and one is likely to be closer to your intended meaning.